# Problems with Unity and the package NavMeshPlus

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navmesh

I am having problems with The package NavMeshPlus for Unity, (used to make the navmesh work for 2D games.) I'm coding in c#, but it's not the coding that is the issue. I'm doing something wrong, but the tutorial seems to be very outdated so I'm sort of feeling around blind. I originally couldn't get the nav mesh to even show up on my screen, then the programmer I'm working with was able to get it to work and I was briefly able to get it to work and now it just... doesn't.

By saying it showed up I mean I could see a blue grid of sorts. The green square in the images had a border that was the white of the "floor" I have under the layout gameobject. Basically the cut out part of the navmesh.

The only change I made between working and not working was to turn the NavMesh gameobject into a prefab. Then I carried it over to a different scene, where it didn't work. When I went back to the test scene it no longer worked. This might be because baking it altered the prefab but I didn't revert or apply any changes to the gameobject in the heirarchy either in the test scene or the scene I tried to implement the navmesh to that had other things on it.

I've attempted to recreate the navmesh from scratch in the test scene, along with recreating that green square since it has the nav mesh obstacle component on it. But nothing makes it work.

The Unity version I'm using is the one that the navmesh was up to date as of, namely 2021.3.8f1. I can't remember where I found that information off the top of my head, though. I think from when I downloaded the sample project Red Hot Sweet Pepper. Previously, my project was a bit behind that, but there have been no issue as far as my project working otherwise so far.

The package itself is up to date.

I'm not familiar with using the Nav Mesh outside of this package as this is my first attempt at using the navmesh at all.

The attached images show what my navmesh gameobject is set up like as well as the green obstacle.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ3uD.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVWWa.png